# Printing a Right-Aligned triangle

Tags: java, computer-science

I need to print a Right aligned triangle like so;

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

This is what I must use to do so, I am stuck as to what I should do.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


}

private static void printWhitespaces(int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
private static void printStars(int amount) {
    for(int i = 0;i < amount; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
private static void printTriangle(int rows) {
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        // Right aligned triangle code

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to print the correct number of spaces before the `*`

You method:

```
private static void printWhitespaces(int size) {
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

won't do that, it will print a number of blank lines. But if you swap `System.out.println()` for `System.out.print()` it should do the trick.

Then, as an example for a triangle of size 5, you would:

- print 4 spaces and a *
- print 3 spaces and 2 *'s
- print 2 spaces and 3 *'s
- print 1 space and 4 *'s
- print 5 *'s.

You can do that in a loop.